# How does one express "want to want" in toki pona?

Tags: toki-pona, translation

For example, "I do not want to want opium"

For example, this doesn't work, it is a yes-no question!

> mi wile ala wile e ijo nasa
>      Do I want a drug?
>       ? Do I want not-want a drug?

The positive doesn't seem to work either

> mi wile wile e ijo nasa
>       * I want [in a wanting manner?] a drug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `mi wile ala e     ni:  mi wile e     ijo   nasa.`
>   `I  want not <obj>-this I  want <obj>-thing crazy`

The same principle as in "I do not want to drink water."

> `mi wile ala e     ni:  mi moku  e     telo.`
>   `I  want not <obj>-this I  drink <obj>-water`

Comment: While I assume OP does not require it, I personally would appreciate it if you could add some form of gloss to the answer so someone not familiar with the language can appreciate the structure as well and learn something from this question.

Comment: The question centers on the word ”ala”, which is used as a negation, but it can also be used to pose a question, as in “sina wile ala wile X?”, do you want or not want X? That's why the attempt to say “mi wile ala wile X”, I want to not want X, can be interpreted as the question “Do I want or not want  X”. The answer given uses the word “ni”, this, as a way out of the problem, by saying “me wile ala e ni: ni wile X”, I do not want this: I want X.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can express something like this as (101). If we imagine a speaker addicted to using their smartphone, they might say something like this.

```
Mi  wile ike    e  ilo  toki. (101)
1sg want bad D.O. tool speak
```

I think *to want badly* in English would map to `wile mute`, since you're talking about extent rather than making a value judgment.

Making a value judgment and describing wanting something as egodystonic are not *exactly* the same thing, but they are similar, at least when talking about oneself.

Answer (score 1):

mi wile e ni: mi wile tawa.
I want this: I want to go.